# calculation of throughput for udp connection in ns3

Tags: c++, network-programming

This is a network question not a programing one:
I have found a piece of code for throughput calculation of a UDP connection which is working fine, I wonder if someone can explain lines below.

What are the measuring units of variables and etc?

```
float totalPacketsThrough = DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverJobs.Get (0))->GetReceived () ;
throughput = totalPacketsThrough * payloadSize * 8 / (simulationTime * 1000000.0);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as UDP connection.

Comment: i've used UdpClientHelper and UdpServerHelper in my code in order to establish a udp connection (i mean sending data on a p2p connection using udp protocol )

Comment: In programming terminology is important. There is particular meaning of term "connnection" in TCP but you call "connection" something else and I think you should not, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of guesswork, but looks pretty straightforward to me:

- `totalPacketsThrough` == number of UDP packets received
- `payloadSize` == size in bytes of payload portion of packets received
- `8` == bits / byte
- `simulationTime` == Time over which the test was run, in seconds.
- `1000000.0` == bits-to-megabits scaling factor

Result is presumably megabits-per-second effective throughput